# ng serve keeps failing referencing missing exported members

Tags: angular, npm

I'm quite new to Angular and I'm not sure where/how to ask questions or how to search for answers effectively, so any insight on this would be helpful.

That said, here's my situation/question:

I've got an application for which I've run `npm install`.  When I run `ng serve`, I get transpilation errors.  One of the errors reads:

> ERROR in M:/MYPATH/src/app/modules/material/material-datagrid/material-datagrid.component.ts (6,10): Module '"M:/MYPATH/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'DataSource'.

In `material-datagrid.component.ts`, I have the following line:

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk';
```

This error happens as soon as I clone the bitbucket repository, run `npm install` and `ng serve`.  My colleagues are downloading from the same repo, but they don't get the error.  We are all on  the same version of Node (6.6.0), and the package.json file is also the same for all of us.

Does anyone know why I'd be the only one getting this error?

Thanks!

Here's my folder hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: did you install `@angular/cdk` ? Could you show `node_modules/@angular`  folder structure?

Comment: Hi @BhavikPatel... I just added the data-source.d.ts file to my table folder.  I'll attache a screenshot of my hierarychy to the main body of the issue.

Comment: Check whether you have different typescript or angular-cli versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I got over this, but I believe the solution was getting the node modules folder from one of my colleagues.  This solution is a total hack, I realize.  The issue was that our dependencies were out of line with each others' environments.  Going forward we are going to be using the package-lock.json file.  Hopefully this resolves things.